# How to use grep to extract a text between two patterns

Tags: bash

I am working with bash script.
There is a file and inside the file, it is like this:

```
Hello /hi/12349/Jane?
Hello /hi/123?=Jane/
Hello /hey/123450/Jane
Hello /hi/123/Jane
```

And I want to extract any digits between "Hello /hi/" and "/", and between "Hello /hi/" and "/" there only should be digits.
So in this case the result I want is:

```
12349
123
```

I have tried this:

```
cat file.txt | grep -o -P '(?>=Hello \/hi\/).*(?=\/)'
```

But what I have tried printed out everything after "Hello /hi" :(

Comment: You have to indent the input file, or put it between lines with triple backticks to create code blocks; otherwise, it'll show up as markdown and it's not clear what your input file really looks like.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sed` for that:

```
sed -nE 's|^Hello /hi/([0-9][0-9]*)/.*|\1|p' file
12349
123
```

Answer (score 1):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po '(?<=^Hello /hi/)[0-9]+(?=/)' file.txt
```

Output:

```
12349
123
```

Answer (score 0):

Extracting things seems like a case to use a Stream EDitor.

```
sed -n '/Hello \/hi\/\([0-9]*\)\.*//s//\1/p' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is an extended regex ( `-E` )...

```
grep -o -E "[^][a-zA-Z /?=]{1,8}" grep.txt
```

...that use a pattern of unwanted chars and `[^]` means in this case: not

> puts out...

```
12349
123
123450
123
```